# Next.js app deployed in serverless can not support ISR

Tags: javascript, next.js, serverless

We have a Next.js app in serverless (tencent scf), and we need Next.js's ISR, but we notice the code deploying space isn't writable. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.